# Concurrency control with method invocation in EJB bean vs. Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, ejb

EJB container serializes all business method invocations by default. And we have a couple of options to change it.

1. Apply the `@Lock(LockType.READ)/@Lock(LockType.WRITE)` annotations.
2. Or set `@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)` annotation on the bean class and use our custom synchronization policy (use syncrnozied blocks or don't use locks at all if bean only reads data, for example). The @Lock annotations is ignored in this case.

My question is how does Spring control it? How does it work be default?
Spring bean may be a stateless bean or may have a state. It can access some resource with read or write operations. And in different situations I need an option to control concurrency.

Could you please explain and compare this aspect of EJB/Spring containers.

Answer (score 0):

EJB declarative concurency management applies only to singleton session beans, see  javax.ejb.ConcurrencyManagement API. Regular session beans have no thread safety issues because containter insures that only one thread accesses a bean instance at any given time. As for Spring beans concurrency is not managed by container, programmers themselves should take care of it.